# What Stack Exchange site should I choose to ask why my CUDA code is slow?

Tags: discussion

I have written my first program using [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) C. But it works much slower than on a CPU, and I need help to understand what I am doing wrong. The code is quite big, ~400 lines. What should I choose - Stack Overflow or maybe Code Review?

Comment: Your code does work? Have you already figured out which part of the 400 lines of the code is the slowest / the hot path?

Comment: @rene, yes, it works. But I'm not sure which part is the slowest. I assume that it may be a heap allocations on GPU memory but they are distributed almost uniformly across all code and I can't check this assumption, neither I can get rid of using heap allocations for a reasonable amount of time, maybe a problem is completely another and maybe the architecture of my code isn't appropriate for a parallelization and I need to rewrite the code from scratch using another approach or maybe I need another way to parallelize my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is not ready to be asked anywhere, to be honest.

I have not used CUDA but I see no reason why the same problem elimination techniques can't be applied that are common in other areas of software engineering. I don't buy your 400 lines program is slow. Only certain aspects of it. Finding the hot-spots in your program is only something you can and need to do. Either use performance tooling, logging or a stopwatch to measure and collect statistics about various aspects of your program.

Once you have isolated them you can either create an Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example or describe a certain set of instructions that are hot in your program flow. That enables you to test one or two different possible solutions.

With that information you can ask a question on Stack Overflow where you describe the problem, your current performance characteristics, what you're aiming for and what you already tried. Possible answers will either address your code issue or suggest a different approach.

Once you have found an answer to your current problem and implemented that to your satisfaction you can present that solution on Code Review to have it reviewed for performance. There they will find another few nano-second for your code.